# Optimizing MATLAB .m file in Python

Tags: python, matlab, optimization

How to define `y=(x-1)^2` function in MATLAB and optimize it in Python with Genetic algorithm.

This problem can be simply done in Python with the following code, but I want to learn it for further complex problems.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.x = pyo.Var(bounds=(-3,3))
x = model.x

def my_function(x):
    return (x-1)**2

model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr= my_function(x), sense=minimize)
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='E:/Py/ipopt/bin/ipopt.exe')
opt.solve(model)
opt.solver.termination_condition)



model.pprint()

x_value = pyo.value(x)


print('x=',x_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try `matlab.engine`

Obviously you would need to install it first, using the instructions provided at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

In Matlab, define the function like this

```matlab
function y = my_function(x)
    y = (x-1)^2;
end
```

Then call it from Python like this:

```py
import matlab.engine
matlab_engine = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
result = matlab_engine.my_function(3.1415)
print(result)
matlab_engine.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. There isn't any problem with calling MATLAB or Octave (or any other language) in Python, but it appears that Python requires explicit functions for optimization, which has made it difficult for me to call an external function in Python for this purpose (By calling an external function I encounter with an error). Despite my efforts to do so for almost a full day, I was unable to achieve the desired result.